# Firing event on disabled button

Tags: sass, ionic2

I want to fire a event on a disabled button

```
  <button ion-button icon-only [disabled]="!isConnected" (click)="openModal()" (disabledClick)="showErrMsg()" shortVibrateOnTap>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-swap" md="ios-swap"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

and if this is not possible, how do I style a button like it is disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disabled class of ionic sets `opacity: 0.4;` on the disabled buttons that gives the visual effect and `pointer-events: none;` that prevents any events from firing.

So if you want to make a button to look like disabled you should create a class

```
.disabled {opacity: 0.4;}
```

Or else you can wrap the button with a div and attach a click event on it:

```
 <div (click)="showErrMsg()">
    <button ion-button icon-only [disabled]="!isConnected" (click)="openModal()"  shortVibrateOnTap>
        <ion-icon ios="ios-swap" md="ios-swap"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

In your `showErrMsg` function make your code to run only when `!isConnected`

Answer (score 1):

I used property binding to solve it.

```
<button ion-button icon-only [style.opacity]="DISABLED_CHECK ? 0.4 : 1" (click)="openModal()"  shortVibrateOnTap>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-swap" md="ios-swap"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

or with a custom disabeld class

```
<button ion-button icon-only [class.disabled]="DISABLED_CHECK" (click)="openModal()"  shortVibrateOnTap>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-swap" md="ios-swap"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

And in my openModal callback function I use the appropriate strategy.